# How is the rootfs size of a docker container decided?

Tags: docker, docker-container, rootfs

On one system, the disk size of the Docker container is like this:

```
root@b65c6518f583:/# df -h
Filesystem                                                                                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-253:0-202764498-b65c6518f5837667e7021971a97aebd382dddca6b3ecf4167472ebe17f16aace   99G  268M   94G   1% /
tmpfs                                                                                                5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
shm                                                                                                   64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                                                5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                                                                5.8G   96K  5.8G   1% /run/secrets
/dev/mapper/rhel-root                                                                                 50G   20G   31G  40% /etc/hosts
```

We can see the rootfs size is 99G. While in another system, the disk size of the Docker container is like this:

```
53ac740bd09b:/ # df -h
Filesystem                                                                                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-8:8-4202821-2a6f330df1b7b37d55a96b098863f81e4a7f1c39fcca3f5fa03b57998cb33427  9.8G  4.4G  4.9G  48% /
tmpfs                                                                                            126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                            126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8                                                                                         97G   11G   82G  12% /data
shm                                                                                               64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

The rootfs size is only 9.8G.

How is the rootfs size of a docker container decided? How can I modify the value of rootfs size?

Answer (score 4):

The default size for a container is 10 GB, and you can change it.

Here is an excerpt from:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/

> `dm.basesize`
>
> Specifies the size to use when creating the base device, which limits
>   the size of images and containers. The default value is 10G. Note,
>   thin devices are inherently “sparse”, so a 10G device which is mostly
>   empty doesn’t use 10 GB of space on the pool. However, the filesystem
>   will use more space for the empty case the larger the device is.
>
> The base device size can be increased at daemon restart which will
>   allow all future images and containers (based on those new images) to
>   be of the new base device size.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> $ docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G
> ```
>
> This will increase the base device size to 50G. The Docker daemon will
>   throw an error if existing base device size is larger than 50G. A user
>   can use this option to expand the base device size however shrinking
>   is not permitted.
>
> This value affects the system-wide “base” empty filesystem that may
>   already be initialized and inherited by pulled images. Typically, a
>   change to this value requires additional steps to take effect:
>
> ```
> $ sudo service docker stop
>
> $ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
>
> $ sudo service docker start
> ```

Example use:

```
$ docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G
```

Comment: Why does the size of the first container is 99G? How can I check the value of current dm.basesize?

Comment: in the file /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage do you have a line DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS= - -storage-opt dm.basesize=99G`  (or 100G)?

Comment: No, there is no value in `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Here's what it would look like in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`: `{"storage-opts": ["dm.basesize=20G"]}`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the docker container to be more than the default size, this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@catap/how-to-increase-docker-container-disk-size-over-devicemapper-1034a0b3df6e) accomplished the task. I know it will work for CentOs 7. With CentOs 6 you only need to change the `xfs_growfs` to `resize2fs`.

I was using docker 1.7